# Docker environment substitution with environment variable replacement

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I'm trying to use environment variable substitution inside a Dockerfile paired with environment variable replacement from docker but it looks like the variable replacement takes place after the substitution.

The following Dockefile:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

ENV name="World"
ENV message="Hello, ${name}"

ENTRYPOINT ["env"]
```

With the Docker run command:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -e "name=Marvin" envtest/helloworld
```

Prints the following environment variables:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=49d702faf257
TERM=xterm
name=Marvin
message=Hello, World
HOME=/root
```

You can see that even though I replaced the name variable, the *message* variable is still substituted with the original value from *name*.

Does anyone know how to do environment variable substitution with dockers environment variable replacement?

**EDIT:** I found [a comment](https://forums.docker.com/t/inline-substitution-for-env-variables/14739) in the Docker forum stating that environment variables are interpreted at build time but can be replaced one by one at runtime. So the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) is a little misleading.

Comment: Regarding your edit at the end.  That's no different than doing exactly the same thing in your shell. If you first set `name` to something, then set `message` to something using `$name`, and then replace the contents of `name` that will not change what is contained in `message`. You'd need to set `message` again in order for it to use the new name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you build the Dockerfile, you get an image. And the image has no knowledege about what was written in the Dockerfile.

That means, the docker image has no knowledge weather `ENV message="Hello, ${name}"` or `ENV message="Hello, world"` was written in the Dockerfile.

It just has it's environment variable as it is, i.e., `name="World"`, `message="Hello, world"`

So, when you start your image using `$ docker run -it --rm -e "name=Marvin" envtest/helloworld`, it overrides the variable `name`, i.e. now `name` is `Marvin`.

But `message` remains `"Hello, world"`.

Because, inside the image, `message` is `"Hello, world"`  not  `"Hello, ${name}"`

Comment: Yup already got that, but thanks. I marked it as accepted answer anyway :) My solution is moving all the substitution stuff inside the shell script I'm running inside the container because in this scenario I only need them in this place.